# Routing not work with scripts unless refresh it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I write two simple page and I want to route from one page (say '/') to another one ('/map') with a Google Map component inside, I place the scripts in a new controller, but nothing come up when I route to the second page unless I refresh it (window.location.replace('#/map') or href = "/map")

```
//routProvider
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

// route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'template/main.html',
        controller  : 'MainController'
    })
    .when('/map', {
        templateUrl : 'template/map.html',
        controller  : 'MapController'
    })
});

// MapController
app.controller('MapController', function($scope, ) {
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
            zoom:5,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});

//Map template
<div>
    <p> this is map</p>
    <div id="googleMap" class="mapcover"></div>
</div>
```

So again the question is how to let the scripts work without refresh when switched to '/map'

Comment: you have any error in console because i see script error in your question i.e after scope you have comaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to simply call your initialize function

> **NOTE**: What **google.maps.event.addDomListener** will do it will bind
>   event on page load so when yo refresh it will trigger but if you call your controller using routes then it is not page load so that your event is not calling so to solve problem call function directly

```
app.controller('MapController', function($scope, ) {
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
            zoom:5,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    }
    initialize();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the addDomListener will do this work.. :P